# I can login only when user's UserName is exacly the same Email in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I created fresh ASP .NET MVC 5 web application with individual accounts(default template). When I create user if I give him different `UserName` and `Email` I cannot login.  If `Email` and `UserName` are the same I can login.

I used default template. What I need change to let `UserName` and `Email` be different?

Put in other words: The problem is that I can login only the user which have `UserName` and `Email` properties equal.

Put in other other words: There are two users, one have: `Email:mailbox@gmail.com`, `UserName:mailbox@gmail.com` I can login as this user. Second user `Email:mailbox@gmail.com`, `UserName:SOMETHING` I cannot log as this user.

Account controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Owin;
using WebApplication2.Models;

namespace WebApplication2.Controllers {
    [Authorize]
    public class AccountController : Controller {
        private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

        public AccountController() {
        }

        public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager) {
            UserManager = userManager;
        }

        public ApplicationUserManager UserManager {
            get {
                return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            }
            private set {
                _userManager = value;
            }
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/Login
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl) {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Login
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl) {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);
                if (user != null) {
                    await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                } else {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/Register
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Register() {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Register
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model) {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
                IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded) {
                    await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);

                    // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                    // Send an email with this link
                    // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                    // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                    // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                } else {
                    AddErrors(result);
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ConfirmEmail
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId, string code) {
            if (userId == null || code == null) {
                return View("Error");
            }

            IdentityResult result = await UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(userId, code);
            if (result.Succeeded) {
                return View("ConfirmEmail");
            } else {
                AddErrors(result);
                return View();
            }
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ForgotPassword
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ForgotPassword() {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/ForgotPassword
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model) {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
                if (user == null || !(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id))) {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user either does not exist or is not confirmed.");
                    return View();
                }

                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Send an email with this link
                // string code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
                // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);       
                // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Reset Password", "Please reset your password by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");
                // return RedirectToAction("ForgotPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ForgotPasswordConfirmation
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ForgotPasswordConfirmation() {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ResetPassword
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ResetPassword(string code) {
            if (code == null) {
                return View("Error");
            }
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/ResetPassword
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ResetPassword(ResetPasswordViewModel model) {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
                if (user == null) {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "No user found.");
                    return View();
                }
                IdentityResult result = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user.Id, model.Code, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded) {
                    return RedirectToAction("ResetPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
                } else {
                    AddErrors(result);
                    return View();
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ResetPasswordConfirmation
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ResetPasswordConfirmation() {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Disassociate
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Disassociate(string loginProvider, string providerKey) {
            ManageMessageId? message = null;
            IdentityResult result = await UserManager.RemoveLoginAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), new UserLoginInfo(loginProvider, providerKey));
            if (result.Succeeded) {
                var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
                await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                message = ManageMessageId.RemoveLoginSuccess;
            } else {
                message = ManageMessageId.Error;
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = message });
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/Manage
        public ActionResult Manage(ManageMessageId? message) {
            ViewBag.StatusMessage =
                message == ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been changed."
                : message == ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been set."
                : message == ManageMessageId.RemoveLoginSuccess ? "The external login was removed."
                : message == ManageMessageId.Error ? "An error has occurred."
                : "";
            ViewBag.HasLocalPassword = HasPassword();
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = Url.Action("Manage");
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Manage
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Manage(ManageUserViewModel model) {
            bool hasPassword = HasPassword();
            ViewBag.HasLocalPassword = hasPassword;
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = Url.Action("Manage");
            if (hasPassword) {
                if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                    IdentityResult result = await UserManager.ChangePasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
                    if (result.Succeeded) {
                        var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
                        await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                        return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess });
                    } else {
                        AddErrors(result);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // User does not have a password so remove any validation errors caused by a missing OldPassword field
                ModelState state = ModelState["OldPassword"];
                if (state != null) {
                    state.Errors.Clear();
                }

                if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                    IdentityResult result = await UserManager.AddPasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), model.NewPassword);
                    if (result.Succeeded) {
                        return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess });
                    } else {
                        AddErrors(result);
                    }
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/ExternalLogin
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl) {
            // Request a redirect to the external login provider
            return new ChallengeResult(provider, Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ExternalLoginCallback
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl) {
            var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (loginInfo == null) {
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            }

            // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login
            var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(loginInfo.Login);
            if (user != null) {
                await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            } else {
                // If the user does not have an account, then prompt the user to create an account
                ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
                ViewBag.LoginProvider = loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider;
                return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel { Email = loginInfo.Email });
            }
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/LinkLogin
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult LinkLogin(string provider) {
            // Request a redirect to the external login provider to link a login for the current user
            return new ChallengeResult(provider, Url.Action("LinkLoginCallback", "Account"), User.Identity.GetUserId());
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/LinkLoginCallback
        public async Task<ActionResult> LinkLoginCallback() {
            var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync(XsrfKey, User.Identity.GetUserId());
            if (loginInfo == null) {
                return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.Error });
            }
            IdentityResult result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), loginInfo.Login);
            if (result.Succeeded) {
                return RedirectToAction("Manage");
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.Error });
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/ExternalLoginConfirmation
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginConfirmation(ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel model, string returnUrl) {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
                return RedirectToAction("Manage");
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                // Get the information about the user from the external login provider
                var info = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
                if (info == null) {
                    return View("ExternalLoginFailure");
                }
                var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
                IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
                if (result.Succeeded) {
                    result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, info.Login);
                    if (result.Succeeded) {
                        await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);

                        // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                        // Send an email with this link
                        // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                        // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                        // SendEmail(user.Email, callbackUrl, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking this link");

                        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                    }
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }

            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/LogOff
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult LogOff() {
            AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ExternalLoginFailure
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ExternalLoginFailure() {
            return View();
        }

        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult RemoveAccountList() {
            var linkedAccounts = UserManager.GetLogins(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            ViewBag.ShowRemoveButton = HasPassword() || linkedAccounts.Count > 1;
            return (ActionResult)PartialView("_RemoveAccountPartial", linkedAccounts);
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
            if (disposing && UserManager != null) {
                UserManager.Dispose();
                UserManager = null;
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Helpers
        // Used for XSRF protection when adding external logins
        private const string XsrfKey = "XsrfId";

        private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager {
            get {
                return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
            }
        }

        private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent) {
            AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
            AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager));
        }

        private void AddErrors(IdentityResult result) {
            foreach (var error in result.Errors) {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
            }
        }

        private bool HasPassword() {
            var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            if (user != null) {
                return user.PasswordHash != null;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private void SendEmail(string email, string callbackUrl, string subject, string message) {
            // For information on sending mail, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
        }

        public enum ManageMessageId {
            ChangePasswordSuccess,
            SetPasswordSuccess,
            RemoveLoginSuccess,
            Error
        }

        private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl) {
            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl)) {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            } else {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }

        private class ChallengeResult : HttpUnauthorizedResult {
            public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri)
                : this(provider, redirectUri, null) {
            }

            public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri, string userId) {
                LoginProvider = provider;
                RedirectUri = redirectUri;
                UserId = userId;
            }

            public string LoginProvider { get; set; }
            public string RedirectUri { get; set; }
            public string UserId { get; set; }

            public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) {
                var properties = new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = RedirectUri };
                if (UserId != null) {
                    properties.Dictionary[XsrfKey] = UserId;
                }
                context.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(properties, LoginProvider);
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Login view:

```
@using WebApplication2.Models
@model LoginViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Log in";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <section id="loginForm">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <h4>Use a local account to log in.</h4>
                <hr />
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Register as a new user", "Register")
                </p>
                @* Enable this once you have account confirmation enabled for password reset functionality
                <p>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Forgot your password?", "ForgotPassword")
                </p>*@
            }
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <section id="socialLoginForm">
            @Html.Partial("_ExternalLoginsListPartial", new ExternalLoginListViewModel { Action = "ExternalLogin", ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

DISCLAIMER: I do not ask how to create users I did.

```
  var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
                    var userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(store);
                    var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));

                    string roleName = "Admin";
                    if (!roleManager.RoleExists(roleName)) {
                        roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole(roleName));
                    }
                    roleName = "TeleMarketer";
                    if (!roleManager.RoleExists(roleName)) {
                        roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole(roleName));
                    }
                    roleName = "Marketer";
                    if (!roleManager.RoleExists(roleName)) {
                        roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole(roleName));
                    }


                    var user = new ApplicationUser() { Email = "informatyka4444@wp.pl", UserName = "Robert" };
                    userManager.Create(user, "TestPass44!");   
                    userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Admin");

                    user = new ApplicationUser() { Email = "s8359@pjwstk.edu.pl", UserName = "Admin" };
                    userManager.Create(user, "TestPass44!");
                    userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Admin");

                    user = new ApplicationUser() { Email = "marketer@wp.pl", UserName = "Marketer" };
                    userManager.Create(user, "TestPass44!");
                    userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "TeleMarketer");

                    user = new ApplicationUser() { Email = "telemarketer@wp.pl", UserName = "TeleMarketer" };
                    userManager.Create(user, "TestPass44!");
                    userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Marketer");
```

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is.  Isn't *the whole point* of a login system to require that the login information be *the same* as an existing record in order to authenticate the user?  What exactly is wrong here?  Also, you've dumped *a lot* of code in this question.  Don't expect anybody to comb through that for you.  Stack Overflow is a poor substitute for a debugger.  Where specifically does this fail?

Comment: @David There are 2 fields in `ApplicationUser`. `Email` and `UserName` I can only login when they are both equal which does not make sense to keep them both. I want to keep them both but I want to be able to use `UserName`.

Comment: As far as my understanding, asp.net identity use user name and password in order to authenticate any user to the system. I can see that you are using another column for email address and asking email address and password for authentication. If you want to use email address and password for user to sign in, then you have to use user name and email same, because asp.net identity framework use user name and password (not your new email table column value and password) for authentication.

Comment: This question should not have been voted down. There is clearly an issue in the background processing that should be noted in the code comments. It is NOT easy to ferret out why it behaves the way it does, and it's even more difficult to figure out a least-impact-fix if the out-of-the-box solution doesn't meet your specific requirements.

Comment: I agree with azarc3. Should not be voted down. Maybe not asked very clearly but is a valid question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is actually very simple and quite reproducible. It looks like the guys at Microsoft took a shortcut and assumed that everyone would always want their email address to be their username. In my case I had a strict requirement where the user name cannot be an email address.

I was able to make the changes necessary to use both fields as truly intended, but when I tried to log in using the scaffolded/provided/out-of-the-box **/Manage/Login.cshtml** view it absolutely forced me to use an email address as the user name. This is *not* the intended behavior because even the under the covers method specifies "username" as the parameter. I don't have this problem when I use my own view/processing to log into the application. And yes, my stuff goes through the same (and official) **SignInManger**.

The validation happening on the client side is what was forcing us to use an email address field value. This doesn't appear to be exposed anywhere that is configurable... and it took me the LONGEST time to find it. I actually felt pretty stupid for about 5 minutes.

The solution (for my scenario) was to...

1. Open the **/Models/AccountViewModels.cs** file.
2. Navigate to the **LoginViewModel** class.
3. On the **Email** property remove (or comment out) the **[EmailAddress]** decorator Attribute.
4. Modify the **Display** decorator Attribute (specifically, the **Name** property) to something appropriate -- fyi, this is what will be shown in the @Html.LabelFor() and validation messages as well.
5. Clear out the browser cache for that site. You can try a hard refresh, but YMMV depending on your browser.
6. Give it a whirl

In my case, problem solved. I hope this helps (even though it's nearly a year later)!

Comment: Finally someody who understood my question. I thought few days ago to ask this question again. Thank you. I'll try that in future, then accept it.

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely into the generated code you will find the LogIn method:

```
    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl) {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);
            if (user != null) {
                await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            } else {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Here you see that the user is being found by using his email address - that is why u have to login using the Email. If you want to change the behaviour - simply modify the LoginViewModel class and the login View.

Comment: This is not the problem. The problem is that I can login only the user which have `UserName` and `Email` properties equal.

Comment: How can this not be a problem? Have you tried looging in by using email and the correct password ?

Comment: Simply, this is not the case I stated in the OriginalPost. I said clearly that I can login when Email and UserName are the same(in database) and can't when they are not. I do not try login using user name. I never stated it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at what you're doing in your `Register` action:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
```

When a user registers, they supply a username and an email.  But you're *ignoring* the username and using the email for *both values*.  I imagine this would be highly unintuitive for users registering in your application.

Try using the username value as the username value:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email };
```

Comment: I know this. I don't know how differently I can describe the problem. Let's try again. Situation: There are two users, one have: `Email:mailbox@gmail.com`, `UserName:mailbox@gmail.com` I can login   as this user. Second user `Email:mailbox@gmail.com`, `UserName:SOMETHING` I cannot log as this user.

Comment: To clarify I used UserManager to create users. When !UserName.Equals(Email); I can't login, when I manually change them to be exact I can.

Comment: @Yoda: When you say "I cannot log as this user." how are you *trying* to login as that user?  What are you providing for the username?  If you're providing `SOMETHING` then, given what I indicated in my answer, how is this behavior surprising to you?  When you create the user you *aren't saving* the username.  You're saving the email address *as* the username.  So you can't login as `SOMETHING` when the username you wrote to the database is `mailbox@gmail.com`.

Comment: I never wrote that I try login providing `UserName`. I login using `Email` and `Password`. I wrote that I can't login when `UserName` and `Email` are different in the database for the user. I honestly checked all stupid things I could've been doing wrong before writing question.

Comment: @Yoda: In that case you're really going to have to be more specific in your question.  Your modeling is using unintuitive names for things and it's not at all clear specifically where the system is failing or what the runtime values are when that happens.  You need to debug it, we can't do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

`Asp.Net` Identity uses username and password to authenticate if you want to login with either username or password check if email is supplied then use the `userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);` to retrieve corresponding username and login check my login code below

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
{
    ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
    if (model.Email.IndexOf('@') > -1)
    {
        //Validate email format
        string emailRegex = @"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}" +
                               @"\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\" +
                                  @".)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$";
        Regex re = new Regex(emailRegex);
        if (!re.IsMatch(model.Email))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "Email is not valid");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //validate Username format
        string emailRegex = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$";
        Regex re = new Regex(emailRegex);
        if (!re.IsMatch(model.Email))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "Username is not valid");
        }
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var userName = model.Email;
        if (userName.IndexOf('@') > -1)
        {
            var user =  await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
            if (user == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
            }
            else
            {
                userName = user.UserName;
            }
        }
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(userName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
```